# How do Possession and Throne Room interact?

Tags: dominion

Does Throne Room cause a Possession card to give you control over two extra turns? I can see it argued both ways convincingly, so I'm looking for an authoritative answer. Google has thus far failed to get me one.

I expect this to be the same as playing the possession card twice on your turn, and related to King's Court.

Comment: The one-line answer is *very poorly for the victim*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From page 3 of the [Alchemy Kingdom Card Description pamphlet](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_356_gameRules.pdf):
  — Possession is cumulative; if you play it twice in one turn, there will be two extra turns after this one.

Also, for reference:
[image]

Comment: However, I prefer to not play with Possession. In my experience it's not a very fun card, unless you're playing with a group of competitively-minded people who will play again if they are totally trounced, which Possession can cause to happen.

Comment: And yes, Throne Room causes you to play a card twice, and King's Court thrice, so the rules definitely would call for multiple possessed turns in this case. Crazy.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I seem to have missed that whole page while reading the rules.

Comment: The real question, speaking as a longtime Magic player, is whether it's possible to take INFINITE turns on behalf of the player to your left, or failing that, as many turns as logistically permitted by some combination of cards...

Comment: I think I could chop up and rephrase half your question as "Is it possible to take as many turns as permitted?" Yes.

Comment: @thesunneversets: Fortunately, throne room on a throne room requires 2 action cards to double, so you don't get exponential growth.

Comment: @thesunneversets: In addition to what @nmichaels said, if, while playing their turn, you force them to play a Possession card, then *they* (not you) take the player to their left's next turn.

Comment: Seriously. This is why I hate this card. :)

Comment: What if, while possessing the other player, you play a Possession card?
**POSSESSION-CEPTION**

Comment: From the pamphlet: "if you make someone play Possession during a turn in which you Possessed them, that will make that player Possess the player to his left, rather than you getting to Possess anyone further."

:)

Comment: @thesunneversets Since there are only 10 possession and 10 king court and no way to play a card more then once since they stay in play instead of going to your discard like magic, so you can't play one card multiply times in a turn so you can only take 30 turns for the player to your left.

Answer (score 1):

The logic on this is very simple, "Throne Room" causes the action to take place twice. That means that "Possession" will occur once, resolve all the way through the first turn, then it will occur a second time, as if you had played another copy of the card that turn.